# Sed insert string at first line of file if the first line matches pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I have an `sed` question to which I couldn't find the answer anywhere yet:

I have a bunch of files, some of them start with the string `###` and some don't. In every file which starts with `###` I would like to insert some multi-line string before the current first line.

f.e. If a file looks like

```
### the first line

abc cba jfkdslfjslkd
```

I want the multi line string to get inserted at the top

```
my
multi
line
string

### the first line

abc cba jfkdslfjslkd
```

Nothing else in the file should get modified.

If a file does not start with `###` then I don't want to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using sed

First let's define your string:

```
$ s='my\nmulti\nline\nstring\n\n'
```

Now, let's run a sed command:

```
$ sed "1s/^###/$s&/" File
my
multi
line
string

### the first line

abc cba jfkdslfjslkd
```

How it works:

- `1s/old/new/` substitutes `new` for `old` but **only** if `old` occurs on the first line.
- `1s/^###/$s&/`  substitutes the string `$s` in front of `###` if the first line starts with `###`.

**Warning:**  The string `s` should not contain any sed-active characters.  If the string `s` is not under your control, this is a security violation.

#### Using awk

Awk has sensible handling of variables and this avoids the security problem.

```
$ s='my\nmulti\nline\nstring\n'
$ awk -v string="$s" 'NR==1 && /^###/ {print string} 1' File
my
multi
line
string

### the first line

abc cba jfkdslfjslkd
```

Comment: I believe (your opinion welcome) my answer avoids the security issue with sed?

Comment: @AlexHarvey In your answer, try `string=$'\n/./w newfile'` and you'll end up with a new file on your file system.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a simpler solution in sed:

Input:

```
▶ string='my\nmulti\nline\nstring\n'
▶ cat FILE 
### the first line

abc cba jfkdslfjslkd

### other lines
```

Solution:

```
▶ gsed -e '1{/^###/i\' -e "$string" -e '}' FILE
my
multi
line
string

### the first line

abc cba jfkdslfjslkd

### other lines"
```

Explanation:

- Use of multiple `-e` allows us to avoid interpolating strings into the sed command.
- The GNU alternative form of [`i\`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) command as noted in the GNU manual.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed and bash

```
$ a='my\nmulti\nline\nstring'; echo -e $a
my
multi
line
string

$  sed -Ee "0,/^###/{/^###/i$a" -e '}' file*

my
multi
line
string
### the first line

abc cba jfkdslfjslkd
```